# How do I clear download history of only the deleted files in Google Chrome Desktop

Tags: google-chrome, download

Refer the following link

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukm5c.png

There is a option for clear all, but I want to clear only those which are Deleted.
Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use Chrome Settings to Clear Browsing Data.  One of the options is to clear Download History.

It is an all or nothing clear (that is, you cannot clear just some), but it allows you do start fresh with Download History.

Answer (score 2):

There's a Chrome Extension for that: [Clear Deleted Downloads](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-deleted-downloads/ffalkaakjbfpeicomidfmddhfimmphol)

Comment: Chrome extensions have been known to cause issues, so adding an extension where you do not need to is hardly a better answer. No need to downvote a good answer.

Comment: The question was, if there is any way to remove only the deleted downloads. There is a way. Saying otherwise is therefore a wrong answer.

Comment: We both had working answers.  I did not say your answer was wrong, only that it was not better enough to downvote another working answer.